# Bootstrap 4 Converting html to Bootstrap 4 Navbar with Logout

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar

I converted my Navbar to bootstrap 4 and it is not clickable.
Here is my original file

```
  <ul id="nav_bar">
    <li style="float:right"><a href="#" onclick="logout(); return false;">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
```

converted to this:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark" id="nav-bar">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Logout</a>                      
    </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new logout link is missing the `onclick`:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark" id="nav-bar">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test</a>
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#" onclick="logout(); return false;">Logout</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Works great Thank You